# How to optimise the re-ordering of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I want to optimize the re-ordering of some data arrays that hold about 4 million unsigned shorts. The aim is to process a data stream by bringing values that should be similar to each other to be close to each other. The pseudo-code is like this:

```
  for( i=0; i<n; i++)
    dest[i] = src[ idx[i] ] ;
```

To optimize the code for a specific list of `idx[i]` I tried to compile a 4 million line c function with the idx values filled in:

```
void reorder( unsigned short * restrict i, unsigned short * restrict o) {
  o[0]=i[2075723];
  o[1]=i[2075724];
  o[2]=i[2075722];
  ...
  o[4194301]=i[4192257];
  o[4194302]=i[4192256];
  o[4194303]=i[4190208];
 }
```

I had hoped to get GCC to create a clever stream of pshufw/pblend/unpack instructions ... instead it hangs after using up a lot of memory (7 GB). I was trying to make copy based version to avoid the complications of doing swaps in place.

Would anyone be able to suggest good ways to produce optimized the code for this problem? So far I tried:

- ordered reading, random writes : 60 ms (openmp didn't help)
- ordered writing, random reads  : 20 ms (openmp -> 4 ms)

I was hoping to end up getting closer to the memory bandwidth (order 0.4 ms). A scheme that takes into account cache size and does blocking should help but I don't know where to start for designing one to do it. I also wonder if there is a simple way to exploit SIMD instructions?

Making a toy example with transpose I couldn't even get gcc to output an SIMD version, see:

https://godbolt.org/z/bzGWad

Is this a difficult problem for compilers or am I missing something simple?

### Edit 21/11/2018 Added a complete but minimal example of the problem

Here is a complete example of the problem I am trying to optimise. In reality the ordering is a more complicated function, but the point is just to order data pixels according to their distance from the image center, like unwinding a spiral.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

#define N 2048

// Sorting on output, one core
void reorder_simple( const std::vector<size_t> &indices,
             const unsigned short input[],
             unsigned short output[]){
  for( int i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    output[i] = input[ indices[i] ];
}
// Sorting on output write, many cores
void reorder_omp( const std::vector<size_t> &indices,
          const unsigned short input[],
          unsigned short output[]){
#pragma omp parallel for
  for( int i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    output[i] = input[ indices[i] ];
}
// Benchmark for memory throughput, one core
void copy_simple(  const std::vector<size_t> &indices,
           const unsigned short input[],
           unsigned short output[]){
  for( int i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    output[i] = input[i];
}
// Benchmark for memory throughput, many cores
void copy_omp (  const std::vector<size_t> &indices,
         const unsigned short input[],
         unsigned short output[]){
#pragma omp parallel for
  for( int i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    output[i] = input[i];
}

// Macro to avoid retyping
#define bench(func)                                          \
  func( indices, input, output);                             \
  start = omp_get_wtime();                                   \
  for( size_t i=0; i<100; i++)                               \
      func( indices, input, output );                        \
  end =  omp_get_wtime();                                    \
  std:: cout << std::setw(15) << #func <<                    \
     ", Time taken: "  << (end-start)/100 << " /s\n";

int main()
{
  std::vector<float> sort_order(N*N);
  std::vector<size_t> indices(N*N);
  float radius, azimuth, ci, cj;
  double start, end;
  unsigned short *input, *output;

  ci = N*0.496;  // changes according to calibration
  cj = N*0.4985;  // reality is more complicated (tilts etc)
  for( size_t i=0; i<N; i++){
    for( size_t j=0; j<N; j++){
      radius  = sqrt( (i-ci)*(i-ci) + (j-cj)*(j-cj) );
      azimuth = atan2( i-ci, j-cj ); // from -pi to pi
      sort_order[i*N+j] = round( radius ) + azimuth/2/M_PI;
      indices[i*N+j] = i*N+j;
    }
  }
  // Find the order to sort data onto a spiral 
  std::sort( indices.begin(), indices.end(),
         [&sort_order](int i, int j){
           return sort_order[i] < sort_order[j]; });
  // Invent some test data
  input = new unsigned short [N*N];
  output = new unsigned short [N*N];
  for( size_t i=0 ; i<N*N; i++){
    input[i] = i;
    output[i]= 0;
  }
  // some timing:
  bench(reorder_simple);
  bench(reorder_omp)   ;
  bench(copy_simple)   ;
  bench(copy_omp)      ;
}


   % g++ reorder.cpp -o reorder -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -fopenmp -Wall
   % ./reorder
     reorder_simple, Time taken: 0.0179023 /s
        reorder_omp, Time taken: 0.00349932 /s
        copy_simple, Time taken: 0.00140805 /s
           copy_omp, Time taken: 0.000250205 /s
```

I would like to get the `reorder_omp` function to be closer to the speed of the `copy_omp` function. Detectors can run at 500 frames per second so 3.5 ms is bad in comparison to 0.25 ms.

### Edit again: 21/11/2018 the code to write the function that does not compile

```
  //top of file
  #include <fstream>  
  ...
  //just before the end: 
  std::ofstream out;
  out.open("cfunc.c");
  out << "void cfunc( unsigned short * restrict input,\n" <<
         "            unsigned short * restrict output){ \n"; 
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
      out << "output[" << i*N+j << "] = input[" << indices[i*N+j] << "];\n";
  out << "}\n";
  out.close();
```

Testing this on a different machine I am getting compiler errors from both gcc (7.3.0) and clang (6.0.0). It compiles and runs with tcc (0.9.27) but finishes slower than the looping over the indices.

Comment: So `idx[]` is a compile-time constant?  Is there a lot of locality in it?  Like groups of destination elements that come from nearby source elements?  But there's no pattern to it so you can't make a loop other than by using gather instructions or scalar?  Is this x86?  What microarchitectures are you tuning for?

Comment: What is the pattern?  The two triplets shown have a `output + (0, 1, 2) = input + (1, 2, 0)` and `output + (0, 1, 2) = input + (1, 0, 2)` pattern.  Writing the same code out 40 times, let alone 4,000,000 times should give you the shivers (you should write a program to write the program, at least!).  I've got a feeling there's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here.

Comment: I'm not sure gcc knows how to build shuffles out of scalar loads/stores like that.  Even if you use `short *__restrict dst` to tell it that src and dst don't overlap to make it possible.  clang might possibly do something, but I'm not surprised the compile-time memory usage was huge.  Your ideas are good; some kind of cache-blocking should be helpful to group reads and writes into small sets of a few (less than 8) cache lines, preferably with some coarser locality with respect to 4k pages too.

Comment: BTW: are your unsigned shorts wider than 16 bits?

Comment: idx is a compile time constant. This is x86 for now but perhaps we should go to a gpu instead. Idx would change from day to day but remain constant for a block of data (some millions of images). The data are 16 bit. There are patterns, the target output is roughly a spiral from the original rectangle image from the detector Perhaps I should put this info above?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, you should add details to your question if you want an answer that actually helps you specifically, rather than an answer to the generic question of optimizing an arbitrary unknown array shuffle.  (With the only thing you can always take advantage of being that it changes infrequently enough to recompile or re-JIT for an `idx`)

Comment: wrt the updated question: `std::vector<size_t> &indices` --<< This is not C

Comment: For the 4 million line example, gcc documents that you are supposed to stop at -O1 and not use higher optimization levels.

Answer (score 0):

(comment section is too short)

I would test the following idea:

1. Maintain reverse index table, so that naive algorithm becomes:

   ```
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      dest[index[i]] = src[i];
    }
   ```
2. Instead of using naive algorithm:

   2.1 Create temporary array of pairs (value, destindex)

   ```
   struct pair {
     int value;
     int destindex;
   };
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     pairs[i] = {.value=src[i], .destindex=index[i]};
   }
   ```

   2.2 Use merge or quick sort to sort array of pairs by `.destindex` field

   2.3 Copy values from array of pairs into `dest` array

There are no random accesses in this algorithm and thus no random access page faults. However, I am not sure that it will work better than naive algorithm because of large number of linear passes.

Comment: The OP already considered your 1. idea, and found "ordered reading, random writes" 3x slower than "ordered writing, random reads".  Sorting could be parallelized and done with better locality, but yeah it's probably not a win.

Comment: I tried something like this, creating small blocks of output (64 values) and ordering these according to what was recently read from improved the run time by about 20%. It helped, but maybe the ordering was still bad for pipelines and there was still no vectorisation.